# How to edit dimension of customview in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, image, view, gif

I want to give custom dimension to custom view but when i open the app, it show me the image in small dimension. In the customview i put a GIF image.

The **CustomGifView.java**

```
public class CustomGifView extends View {

private InputStream gifInputStream;
private Movie gifMovie;
private int movieWidth, movieHeight;
private long movieDuration;
private long mMovieStart;

public CustomGifView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init(context);
}

public CustomGifView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init(context);
}

public CustomGifView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,
                     int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    init(context);
}

private void init(Context context){
    setFocusable(true);
    gifInputStream = context.getResources()
            .openRawResource(R.drawable.caricamento);

    gifMovie = Movie.decodeStream(gifInputStream);
    movieWidth = gifMovie.width();
    movieHeight = gifMovie.height();
    movieDuration = gifMovie.duration();
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec,
                         int heightMeasureSpec) {
    setMeasuredDimension(movieWidth, movieHeight);
}

public int getMovieWidth(){
    return movieWidth;
}

public int getMovieHeight(){
    return movieHeight;
}

public long getMovieDuration(){
    return movieDuration;
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    long now = android.os.SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
    if (mMovieStart == 0) {   // first time
        mMovieStart = now;
    }

    if (gifMovie != null) {

        int dur = gifMovie.duration();
        if (dur == 0) {
            dur = 1000;
        }

        int relTime = (int)((now - mMovieStart) % dur);

        gifMovie.setTime(relTime);

        gifMovie.draw(canvas, 0, 0);
        invalidate();

    }

}
```

The **caricamento.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:components="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#398596">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Caricamento in corso..."
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:layout_marginBottom="37dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Tip: Lo sapevi che il QR Scanner rileva automaticamente il codice del tavolo?"
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_marginBottom="76dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="55dp" />

<com.faddex.ristorante.CustomGifView
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:id="@+id/view"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

As you can see at the end i give 300dp - 300dp but when i open the activity in the smartphone it show always small dimension, even if i change to 10000dp - 10000dp

Comment: considering you completely dismiss the values of widthMeasureSpec & heightMeasureSpec, the xml values will always be pointless

Comment: what i need to do?

Comment: I'm not sure what it is you want to do , you say "edit dimension" but edit to what goal? make it fit , crop or stretch or something entirely different?

Comment: i want that the gif become 300 x 300, the real dimension of the gif is 268 x 268 but in the activity it become like 100 x 100 or less

Comment: done, i resized the gif to 600 x 600 with an online gif resizer

Comment: then you need to consider using the "measured height and weight" in your custom view. currently you're discarding those values and just setting them to gifMovie.width() and gifMovie.height(); probably also need to set scaleType to make the resource stretch to ImageView size